# How to obtain only the first True value from each row of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4x3 boolean numpy array, and I'm trying to return a same-sized array which is all False, except for the location of the first True value on each row of the original. So if I have a starting array of

```
all_bools = np.array([[False, True, True],[True, True, True],[False, False, True],[False,False,False]])
all_bools
array([[False,  True,  True], # First true value = index 1
       [ True,  True,  True], # First true value = index 0
       [False, False,  True], # First true value = index 2
       [False, False, False]]) # No True Values
```

then I'd like to return

```
[[False, True, False],
 [True, False, False],
 [False, False, True],
 [False, False, False]]
```

so indices 1, 0 and 2 on the first three rows have been set to True and nothing else. Essentially any True value (beyond the first on each row) from the original way have been set to False.

I've been fiddling around with this with np.where and np.argmax and I haven't yet found a good solution - any help gratefully received. This needs to run many, many times so I'd like to avoid iterating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy-cumsum), and find the first bool by comparing the result with 1.

```
all_bools.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) == 1 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

This also accounts for the issue @a_guest pointed out. The second `cumsum` call is needed to avoid matching all `False` values between the first and second `True` value.

---

If performance is important, use [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy-argmax) and set values:

```
y = np.zeros_like(all_bools, dtype=bool)
idx = np.arange(len(x)), x.argmax(axis=1)
y[idx] = x[idx]

y
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

---

**Perfplot Performance Timings**
I'll take this opportunity to show off `perfplot`, with some timings, since it is good to see how our solutions vary with different sized inputs.

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

def cs1(x):
    return  x.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) == 1 

def cs2(x):
    y = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool)
    idx = np.arange(len(x)), x.argmax(axis=1)
    y[idx] = x[idx]
    return y

def a_guest(x):
    b = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool)
    i = np.argmax(x, axis=1)
    b[np.arange(i.size), i] = np.logical_or.reduce(x, axis=1)
    return b

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n, n)).astype(bool),
    kernels=[cs1, cs2, a_guest],
    labels=['cs1', 'cs2', 'a_guest'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 8)],
    xlabel='N'
)
```

[image]

The trend carries forward to larger N. `cumsum` is very expensive, while there is a constant time difference between my second solution, and @a_guest's.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following approach using `np.argmax` and a product with `np.logical_or.reduce` for dealing with rows that are all `False`:

```
b = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool)
i = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
b[np.arange(i.size), i] = np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=1)
```

#### Timing results

Different versions in increasing performance, i.e. fastest approach comes last:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: def f(a):
   ...:     return a.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) == 1
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [3]: def g(a):
   ...:     b = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool)
   ...:     i = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
   ...:     b[np.arange(i.size), i] = np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=1)
   ...:     return b
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [4]: x = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1000, 1000)).astype(bool)

In [5]: %timeit f(x)
10.4 ms ± 155 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit g(x)
120 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: def h(a):
   ...:     y = np.zeros_like(x)
   ...:     idx = np.arange(len(x)), x.argmax(axis=1)
   ...:     y[idx] += x[idx]
   ...:     return y
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [8]: %timeit h(x)
92.1 µs ± 3.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [9]: def h2(a):
    ...:     y = np.zeros_like(x)
    ...:     idx = np.arange(len(x)), x.argmax(axis=1)
    ...:     y[idx] = x[idx]
    ...:     return y
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [10]: %timeit h2(x)
78.5 µs ± 353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```